# Configuring Mediawiki UTCLiveClock Gadget

Tags: javascript, mediawiki

I am working with MediaWiki's UTCLiveClock.js and I am trying to configure it to put out a display time in PST/PDT. I thought I fixed the problem, however when midnight UTC hit (00:00:00) it changed my time output to 0-7:00:00. I need to to display properly so that when UTC 00:00:00 - 07:00:00 occurs, my time display doesn't look a mess. The gadget I am using through mediawiki can be found at https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki:Gadget-UTCLiveClock.js

Yes, I'm a noob. I don't have any formal programming knowledge. I'm just trying to build a wiki for a game whose server exists in PST/PDT and running into this problem. Googling keyword searches for the last 3 hours has gotten me nowhere. Please help.

```
    */
/*global mw, $, UTCLiveClockConfig:true */
mw.loader.using(['mediawiki.util', 'mediawiki.api', 'mediawiki.notify']).then( function () {
var $target;

function showTime( $target ) {
    var now = new Date();
    var hh = now.getUTCHours();
    var mm = now.getUTCMinutes();
    var ss = now.getUTCSeconds();
    var time = ( hh < 10 ? '0' + hh : hh ) + ':' + ( mm < 10 ? '0' + mm : mm ) + ':' + ( ss < 10 ? '0' + ss : ss );
    $target.text( time );

    var ms = now.getUTCMilliseconds();

    setTimeout( function () {
        showTime( $target );
    }, 1100 - ms );
}

function liveClock() {
    mw.util.addCSS( '#utcdate a { font-weight:bolder; font-size:120%; }' );

    if ( !window.UTCLiveClockConfig ) {
        UTCLiveClockConfig = {};
    }
    var portletId = UTCLiveClockConfig.portletId || 'p-personal';
    var nextNode = UTCLiveClockConfig.nextNodeId ? document.getElementById( UTCLiveClockConfig.nextNodeId ) : undefined;
    var node = mw.util.addPortletLink(
        portletId,
        mw.util.getUrl( null, { action: 'purge' } ),
        '',
        'utcdate',
        null,
        null,
        nextNode
    );
    if ( !node ) {
        return;
    }
    $( node ).on( 'click', function ( e ) {
        new mw.Api().post( { action: 'purge', titles: mw.config.get( 'wgPageName' ) } ).then( function () {
            location.reload();
        }, function () {
            mw.notify( 'Purge failed', { type: 'error' } );
        } );
        e.preventDefault();
    } );

    showTime( $( node ).find( 'a:first' ) );
}

$( liveClock );
} );
```

edit:

the way i originally fixed the problem is by putting a -7 in the hours section:

```
var hh = now.getUTCHours()-7;
```

Comment: There should be better link for this ‘Gadget’. Where do You get it from?

Comment: Directly from Mediawiki
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Gadgets

My problem is there is absolutely NO tutorial on how to edit the .js to make it suitable for another time zone. I can't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks this is very simple Gadget limited to time in UTC. There are few options.

1. Find better script with support for time zones.
2. Write own script based on this one.

To write own script, there is critical part.

```
function get_PST_PDT_offset() {
    /* You have to rewrite this function from time to time. */
    var now = new Date();
    var change = new Date(2016, 11, 5, 19, 0); /* 2016-11-06 2:00 PST */
    if (now >= change) {
        return -8;
    } else {
        return -7;
    }
}

function showTime( $target ) {
    var now = new Date();
    var hh = now.getUTCHours();
    var offset = get_PST_PDT_offset();
    hh = (hh + offset + 24) % 24;
    var mm = now.getUTCMinutes();
    /* ... */
```

Comment: thank you, you're right it would seem simple enough but i'm usually frankensteining together everything i've been using... coming up with .js code myself isn't something i'm capable of yet... so i gave up on looking through manuals and tutorials and just decided to ask.

Comment: also this answer worked like a charm, i've upvoted you but my rep is too low for it to count publicly for anything, but my deepest thanks are there nonetheless